# VB 2010 Express: Debug.WriteLine optimized away completely in debug version?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, debugging, compiler-optimization

Simple question that does not seem to be covered: **If I use a lot of `Debug.WriteLine` statements in my code, will they be completely absent in my production version?**

I mean: Is the compiler smart enough to not emit any code for those calls? Or would I have to surround them by `#if DEBUG..#end` if directives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debug class members are marked with ConditionalAttribute thus call sites won't be compiled if the build is done in Release mode

See the top of this page
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9z9k5ydz.aspx

Comment: In addition, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute.aspx tells the story behind it.

Answer (score 1):

If you build your project in RELEASE mode all the [Debug.WriteLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline.aspx) statements are omitted cause they are decorated with the [ConditionalAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute.aspx) set to DEBUG.

This is done at compile time. You can check this when you analyze your assemblies with a decompiler (such as .NET Reflector, dotNetPeek). If you build in DEBUG mode the calls to Debug.WriteLine are present. If you build it in RELEASE mode the calls are not present.

Comment: Thanks. Accepting the question of the guy with the smaller amount of reputation points if you won't be pissed.

Comment: @TheBlastOne: Accept the answer that helps you most.

Comment: @Jehof I am embarrassed enough due to the RTF nature of the question, so I won't accept an answer from a 7k+ respect point owner. (Joking)

Comment: @kmcc049 I cannot see that you were first. "Answered 1 minute ago" on both answers initially. Meanwhile, Farber's is "11 mins ago", yours is "13 mins ago". But -- who cares, really :)

Comment: @TheBlastOne : do what you want. It is your decision

Answer (score 1):

Debug class output works only in Debug configuration. Trace class works both in Debug and Release. So, you don't need to use #if DEBUG.

Comment: I know that. They have no impact in production versions. The question was if that is handled at run-time, or at compile-time.